# Why we use .ToSelf() in ninject what's the main logic behind that

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

I am working on Ninject as new i have one queestion from below code in Class "Warrior Module"
        we have bindeed interface with class thatis understood but why we use .ToSelf() with class SWORD 
        I have done google but i cant get the exact logic behind this..what if i remove the line

```
Bind<Sword>().ToSelf();
```

Below Code

```
//interface
        interface IWeapon
        {
            void Hit(string target);
        }
        //sword class
        class Sword : IWeapon
        {
            public void Hit(string target)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Killed {0} using Sword", target);
            }
        }

         class Soldier
        {
            private IWeapon _weapon;
            [Inject]
            public Soldier(IWeapon weapon)
            {
                _weapon = weapon;
            }
            public void Attack(string target)
            {
                _weapon.Hit(target);
            }
        }

         class WarriorModule : NinjectModule
        {
            public override void Load()
            {
                Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();

                Bind<Sword>().ToSelf();//why we use .Toself() with self
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new WarriorModule());

            Soldier warrior = kernel.Get<Soldier>();

            warrior.Attack("the men");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Check if this answer is enough for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218830/ninject-basics-with-example-please. Basically that line is equal to `Bind<Sword>().To<Sword>()`

Comment: thanks @3615 already gone through this link and other stuff also that's why i posted here..but i like your answer also Bind<Sword>().To<Sword>()

Comment: Usually you would bind some interface to it's implementation, but sometimes you may need to have the class itself registered in the IoC container. In this case you would make that binding, and to make it more readable it was given an alias `.ToSelf()`

Answer (score 6):

Ninject allows resolution of ["self-bindable"](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Planning/Bindings/Resolvers/SelfBindingResolver.cs#L69) types even if they have no explicit binding.

It then defaults to the equivalent of

```
Bind<Foo>().ToSelf()
    .InTransientScope();
```

Note:

- The `ToSelf()` binding is equivalent to `Bind<Foo>().To<Foo>()`.
- When you don't specify a scope it defaults to `InTransientScope()`. So when you write `Bind<Foo>().ToSelf();` that is also equivalent to `Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();`

### Conclusion

In conclusion you only **need** to write a binding for a self-bindable type if you want it to be different from the default, for example:

```
Bind<Foo>().ToSelf()
    .InRequestScope();
```

or

```
Bind<Foo>().ToSelf()
    .OnActivation(x => x.Initialize());
```

or

```
Bind<Foo>().To<SpecialCaseFoo>();
```

I also think that at some point there was (or still is) an option to deactivate the "self-binding" auto-binding behavior, in which case a `Bind<Foo>().ToSelf()` can make sense, too.